# Find and replace using a list in text file?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but sure am hoping that it is.

I have this line 766 times in the file backup.xml:

```
*** Hosting Services
```

I then have the file `list.txt` which contains 766 lines in it.  I need to replace `***` with the contents of each of the 766 lines in `list.txt` - and it needs to be in the same order if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sure its possible. What have you tried? Is there only 1 instance of `***`. or are there many of them?

Comment: I have `***` 766 times in `backup.xml`.  I need each of those instances replaced with each of the 766 lines that are in `list.txt`.  I know how to find and replace via command line but can't find anything definitive about how to do the replacing from a list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea:**

```
loop over the lines of the B(ackup file)
  if you (F)ind a B-line to change
     read the next line of the L(ist file)
     change
  print the line to R(result file)
```

**Plan:**

```
read_open B
read_open L
write_open R
while (line from B)
  if (F) {
    read replacemment from L
    change line
  }
  print line to R
}
close R, L, B
```

**Implementation I (read_open, loop, look at B):**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);

my $bfn = '../data/AA-backup-xml';
open my $bfh, '<', $bfn or die "Can't read open '$bfn': $OS_ERROR";
while (my $line = <$bfh>) {
        print $line;
}
close $bfh or die "Can't read close '$bfn': $OS_ERROR";
```

output:

```
perl 01.pl
whatever
whatever
*** Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
whatever
*** Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
*** Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
whatever
*** Hosting Services
```

**Implementation II (read/write, F, replace, first result):**

```
use Modern::Perl;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);

my $bfn = '../data/AA-backup-xml';
open my $bfh, '<', $bfn or die "Can't read open '$bfn': $OS_ERROR";
my $lfn = '../data/AA-list.txt';
open my $lfh, '<', $lfn or die "Can't read open '$lfn': $OS_ERROR";
my $rfn = '../data/AA-result';
open my $rfh, '>', $rfn or die "Can't write open 'rlfn': $OS_ERROR";
while (my $line = <$bfh>) {
    if ($line =~ /\*{3}/) {
        my $rpl = <$lfh>;
        $rpl = substr($rpl, 0, 3);
        $line =~ s/\*{3}/$rpl/;
    }
    print $rfh $line;
}
close $rfh or die "Can't write close '$rfn': $OS_ERROR";
close $lfh or die "Can't read close '$lfn': $OS_ERROR";
close $bfh or die "Can't read close '$bfn': $OS_ERROR";
```

output:

```
type ..\data\AA-result
whatever
whatever
001 Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
whatever
002 Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
003 Hosting Services
whatever
whatever
whatever
004 Hosting Services
```

If this does not 'work' for you (perhaps I mis-guessed the structur of B or the F strategy is too naive), then publish a representative sample of B, L, and R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tie::File` to look at/modify files through representing them as arrays, ie:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

tie my @ra1, 'Tie::File', "test.txt" or die; #*** Hosting Services
tie my @ra2, 'Tie::File', "test1.txt" or die; #stuff you want to replace *** with

#assumes equal length
for (my $i=0; $i <= $#ra1; $i++)
{
    my $temp=$ra2[$i];
    $ra1[$i]=~s/(\*{3})/$temp/; 
}

untie @ra1;
untie @ra2;
```

The above code replaces `***` with the corresponding line of your list file.  By writing `$ra1[$i]=~s/(\*{3})/$temp/` we are directly changing the file that @ra1 is tied to.

Comment: That renamed about 15 of the instances of `***` but then started showing the error `Use of uninitialized value $temp in substitution (s///) at rename.bat line 12, $fh> line 56737.` and just added a blank space where *** was for all the rest.

Comment: The files are not of the same size, then.

Comment: The file `list.txt` is exactly 766 lines long.
The file `backup.xml` shows `***` exactly 766 times.  However, `backup.xml` has a total over 28,000 lines.

Comment: Assuming that there's text in each line and the files have the same number of lines, I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I thought you were talking about `***` being mentioned the same amount of time as lines I have in `list.txt`  The file `backup.xml` is longer - about 28,000 lines.

Comment: This method will only work if the files are as described above.  Are there equal entries in both files, but one is just longer?  If so, then you can modify the above by searching for `$temp` from some entry, whatever will be replacing `***`, and assigning that to `$ra1[$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a linenum=0
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('findstr /n "$" ^<backup.xml') DO (
 SET "line=%%i"
 SET "line=!line:*:=!"
 IF DEFINED line (
  IF "!line!"=="*** Hosting Services" (
   SET /a linenum+=1
   FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%r IN ('findstr /n "$" ^<list.txt') DO (
    IF !linenum!==%%r (ECHO(%%s Hosting Services) 
   )
  ) ELSE (ECHO(!line!)
 ) ELSE (ECHO()
)
)>new.xml

GOTO :eof
```

IIUC, this should replace each `"*** Hosting Services"` line from `backup.xml` with `line corresponding from list.txt *** Hosting Services`, creating a new file `new.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty short and sweet in awk:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {list[FNR]=$0; next}
    /\*\*\* Hosting Services/ {sub(/\*\*\*/, list[++count])}
    {print}
' list.txt backup.xml > new_backup.xml
```

[`a2p`](http://man.cx/a2p) turns that into

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';       # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";      # set output record separator

line: while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    if ($. == ($.-$FNRbase)) {
        $list{($.-$FNRbase)} = $_;
        next line;
    }
    if (/\*\*\* Hosting Services/) {
        ($s_ = '"'.($list{++$count}).'"') =~ s/&/\$&/g, s/\*\*\*/eval $s_/e;
    }
    print $_;
}
continue {
    $FNRbase = $. if eof;
}
```