# Replacing text in a file from a list in another file?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

[I asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16727955/7552) but don't think I really explained it properly based on the answers given.

I have a file named `backup.xml` that is 28,000 lines and contains the phrase `***` in it 766 times.  I also have a file named `list.txt` that has 766 lines in it, each with different keywords.

What I basically need to do is insert each of the lines from `list.txt` into `backup.xml` to replace the 766 places `***` is mentioned.

Here's an example of what's contained in `list.txt`:

```
Anaheim
Anchorage
Ann Arbor
Antioch
Apple Valley
Appleton
```

Here's an example of one of the lines with `***` in it from `backup.xml`:

```
<title>*** Hosting Services - Company Review</title>
```

So, for example, the first line that has `***` mentioned should be changed to this according to the sample above:

```
<title>Anaheim Hosting Services - Company Review</title>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any examples of input and desired output?

Comment: Just updated question for you.

Comment: I saw the previous question first. My answer there is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can probably get away with treating the XML as pure text.
So read the XML  file, and replace each occurrence of the marker with a line read from the keyword file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

my $xml_file  = 'backup.xml';
my $list_file = 'list.txt';
my $out_file  = 'out.xml';  

my $pattern='***';

# I assumed all files are utf8 encoded
open( my $xml,  '<:utf8', $xml_file  );
open( my $list, '<:utf8', $list_file );
open( my $out,  '>:utf8', $out_file  );

while( <$xml>)
  { s{\Q$pattern\E}{my $kw= <$list>; chomp $kw; $kw}eg;
    print {$out} $_;
  }

rename $out_file, $xml_file;
```

Comment: why braces in `print {$out} $_;`

Comment: It makes sure that `$out` is used as a filehandle. They're not necessary here, but I use them anyway, as I find it makes it more obvious for the reader that the `print` is foint to `$out`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
awk '{print NR-1 ",/\\*\\*\\*/{s/\\*\\*\\*/" $0 "/}"}' list.txt > list.sed
sed -f list.sed backup.xml
```

The first line used `awk` to make a list of search/replace commands based on the list, which is then executed on the next line via `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`. It reads `backup.xml` file and when found a `***` text, I extract a word from the `list.txt` file. The `BEGIN` block removes `list.txt` from the argument list to avoid its processing. The order of arguments is very important. Also I assume that there is only one `***` string per line.

```
awk '
        BEGIN { listfile = ARGV[2]; --ARGC }
        /\*\*\*/ {
                getline word <listfile
                sub( /\*\*\*/, word )
        }
        1     ## same as { print }
' backup.xml list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two files sequentially correspond, you can use `paste` command to join lines from both files and then postprocess.

```
paste list.txt backup.xml | 
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {sub(/\*\*\*/, $1); print substr($0, length($1)+2)}'
```

paste command will produce the following:

```
Anaheim \t <title>*** Hosting Services - Company Review</title>
```

while the one-liner in AWK will replace *** with the first field, subsequently removing the first field and the field separator (\t) after it.

Another variation is:

```
paste list.txt backup.xml | 
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {sub(/\*\*\*/, $1); print $0}' | 
cut -f 2-
```

Comment: From the question, you can't assume the two files have the same number of lines, so paste won't work.

Comment: that's why I started with 'if' statement